# Relative filepath to access resources

Tags: java, swt, rcp, e4

I am quite new to Eclipse 4, RCP and SWT and I am stuck on this issue :
I want to access image resources from code with a relative filepath. Problem is that the default location `./` is set to my home directory `/home/name/` (I'm using Ubuntu). I have found that by creating a new File and printing its CanonicalPath.

I am used to having the default location set to the project directory, such as `/home/name/workspace/project/`, which is, from what I've seen so far, the default behavior in Eclipse / java programs.

I would like to keep this behavior because it seems more reliable to me (after deployment for example).

**Note**: I have tagged e4, rcp and swt because I'm not sure which one causes the difference.

Comment: Is this a plugin, RCP or an SWT app?

Comment: You can try using Classname.class.getClassLoader().getResource(name); ?

Comment: As I said, being new to this, I'm not 100% sure of their relations and differences. (Unfortunately I have to use them anyway). I can tell that I'm using `@Inject`and `@PostConstruct` annotations which I think are from RCP. And I'm also using SWT to create windows etc. Long story short, I would say RCP. I hope I'm right. (I will add that to my question actually)

Comment: @KirickParty I'm looking at this right now but it seems that SWT does not allow `URL` as a image path.

Comment: @KirickParty Well anyway, it doesn't seem to find the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an Eclipse plugin (including RCP code) you should use the `FileLocator` class to find resources within the plugin.

You open a resource as a stream:

```
Bundle bundle = ... plugin bundle

IPath path = new Path("path relative to plugin root");

InputStream is = FileLocator.openStream(bundle, path, true);
```

You can also use `FileLocator.find`:

```
URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, path, null);

URL fileUrl = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
```

Don't forget to include your resources directory in the `build.properties`.

If your image is not in the plugin you can't really use relative paths.

In an e4 plugin you can inject the `Bundle` using `@OSGiBundle`:

```
@Inject
@OSGiBundle
Bundle bundle;
```

(`@OSGiBundle` requires a dependency on the  `org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions` plugin).

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the `Bundle` object. I tried via injection but it does not work.

Comment: Do I need something more ? Because it cannot resolve the `@OSGiBundle` annotation. There is no problem with `org.osgi.framework.Bundle` though.

Comment: You need to add `org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions` to the plugin dependencies.

Comment: Well, now it works :) I also made another mistake which was to access `bundle` in the constructor instead of a `@PostConstruct` method so it stayed `null`. Anyway, it found my image now so everything is good. Thank you.